# Problems with Importing a pdf from an url

Tags: bugs, import, pdf-format, crash, data-acquisition

I have to process a lot of information from different pdf. I already have the code to download all the files, but i'm stuck in the part where i have to open the files with "Import".

For example:
http://www.hidraulica.gob.ar/precipitaciones_historial/QzAzMTFfMjAxNg==

If i tried to open the file using:

```
Import[link,"PDF"]
```

Mathematica just crash... i got an "**Internal self-test-error: winFonts|c|982**"

I was able to import the file using the format "Plaintext", but i couldn't save the data as a csv, because the "spaces" aren't constant (that's why i wanted to import the file as a pdf to get the coordinates from the texts)

Comment: *Mathematica* 8.0.4 on Windows 7 x64 gets completely frozen after an attempt to import this PDF file (both from the URL and as a local file). Obviously it is a bug in the PDF importer.

Comment: Please report this to the tech support.

Comment: You do understand that link provided is not an actual pdf, but leads you to a pdf view. You need to feed Import with a url with .pdf extention in order to work. for example `Import["http://www.unipi.gr/faculty/mbouts/sim/Intro_to_Mathematica08.pdf","PDF"]`

Comment: @TomZinger Actually *Mathematica* successfully follows redirects and indeed imports the PDF (not a web page or a preview). As I mentioned above, the same happens when one attempts to import a local copy of the file.

Comment: @Alexey Popkov i was able to import the pdf file (removing manually an element from the pdf). But the texts moved from their original places... i could make an OCR, but i need a way to automatically import the pdf as an image, without distortions